# How to solve this C/Linux exercise?

Tags: c, linux

I have not clearly understood the C/Linux exercise below :

**The exercise :**

Taking into consideration the following dependency graph, which express dependency relations between 4 tasks of a program :

[image]

We want to create 4 processes (S1 to S4) which will be executed in parallel in order to automate the dependency graph above. Each process Si will be based on the model 1 below :

[image]

Propose a solution and clearly justify it.

If anyone understands this exercise, please feel free to explain it. Thank for the help !

Comment: In a precedence graph such as this one, does T5 have to wait for both T2 and T3 to be done, or can it run as soon as either one is done?  I'd have naively thought the former, but your logic corresponds to the latter case.

Comment: 1.) Please do not post pictures of code, but instead type it and (preferably) use the code tags. 2.) What code have you come up and tried? The SO community is not one to usually write others homework/exercises without at least something done by the poster.

Comment: You cannot delete content like that. People have answered it. Destroying your question invalidates their answer. If you don't want it online, you shouldn't have asked the question. By posting it here you have irrevocably and perpetually licensed the content to the site. Please leave it in place.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of your code is that using that you must put those if in a loop, so you continuously check if the previous task is done or not yet. So you lose time in tests that often will be false.

It's better to use the semaphores to synchronise these processes: if the semaphore count is 0 the thread will be suspended and wake up again automatically when the previous task is finished.

For example for the process P2 you can use:

```
sem_wait(sem_1)
T2
sem_post(sem_2)
```